# error: Type '[Assembly-UnityScript] extra field

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, user-input, unityscript

I have this script here and for some reason I get this error.

> Type '[Assembly-UnityScript]PlayerGUI' has an extra field
>   'healthFallRate' of type 'System.Int32' in the player and thus can't
>   be serialized (expected 'healthBarDisplay' of type 'System.Single')
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

```
#pragma strict

//Size of Textures
var size : Vector2 = new Vector2(240, 40);
var sizeXP1 : Vector2 = new Vector2(40, 20);
var sizeXP2 : Vector2 = new Vector2(100, 20);

//Health Variables
var healthPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 20);
var healthFallRate : int = 150;
var healthBarDisplay : float = 1;
var healthBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var healthBarFull : Texture2D;

//Hunger Variables
var hungerPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 60);
var hungerFallRate : int = 150;
var hungerBarDisplay : float = 1;
var hungerBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var hungerBarFull : Texture2D;

//Thirst Variables
var thirstPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 100);
var thirstFallRate : int = 100;
var thirstBarDisplay : float = 1;
var thirstBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var thirstBarFull : Texture2D;

//Stamina Variables
var staminaPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 140);
var staminaFallRate : int = 35;
var staminaBarDisplay : float = 1;
var staminaBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var staminaBarFull : Texture2D;

//Level Up System
var currentXPPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 180);
var currentXP : int = 0;
var maxXP : int = 50;
var level : int = 1;
private var leveledUp : boolean = true;
var timeToShowLevelUp : float = 3f;
var timeTillNotShowLevelUp : float = 0f;

private var chMotor : CharacterMotor;
private var controller : CharacterController;

var canJump : boolean = false;

var jumpTimer : float = 0.7;

var beginningSound : AudioClip;

private var deathMenu : DeathMenu;

function Start () {
    chMotor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
    controller = GetComponent(CharacterController);

    deathMenu = GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(DeathMenu);

    yield WaitForSeconds (5);

    audio.PlayOneShot(beginningSound);
}

function OnGUI () {
    //Health GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (healthPos.x, healthPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), healthBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * healthBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), healthBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Hunger GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (hungerPos.x, hungerPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), hungerBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * hungerBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), hungerBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Thirst GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (thirstPos.x, thirstPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), thirstBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * thirstBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), thirstBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Stamina GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (staminaPos.x, staminaPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), staminaBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * staminaBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), staminaBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (currentXPPos.x, currentXPPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 20, sizeXP1.x, sizeXP1.y), "XP");
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, sizeXP1.x, sizeXP1.y), "Level");
    GUI.Box(new Rect(40, 20, sizeXP2.x, sizeXP2.y), currentXP + "/" + maxXP);
    GUI.Box(new Rect(40, 0, sizeXP2.x, sizeXP2.y), level + "");
    GUI.EndGroup();
    //currentXPPos
}

function Update() {
    //Health Control
    if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0 && (thirstBarDisplay <= 0)) {
        healthBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate * 2;
    }

    else {
        if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0 || thirstBarDisplay <= 0) {
            healthBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate;
        }
    }

    if(healthBarDisplay <= 0) {
        deathMenu.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("deathMenu.enabled");
    }

    //Hunger Control
    if(hungerBarDisplay >= 0) {
        hungerBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / hungerFallRate;
    }

    if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0) {
        hungerBarDisplay = 0;
    }

    if(hungerBarDisplay >= 1) {
        hungerBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    //Thirst Control
    if(thirstBarDisplay >= 0) {
        thirstBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / thirstFallRate;
    }

    if(thirstBarDisplay <= 0) {
        thirstBarDisplay = 0;
    }

    if(thirstBarDisplay >= 1) {
        thirstBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    //Stamina Control
    if(controller.velocity.magnitude > 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 10;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 10;
        staminaBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / staminaFallRate;
    }

    else {
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 6;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 6;
        staminaBarDisplay += Time.deltaTime / staminaFallRate;
    }

    //Jumping Section
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump == true) {
        staminaBarDisplay -= 0.2;
        Wait();
    }

    if(canJump == false) {
        jumpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
    }

    if(jumpTimer <= 0) {
        canJump = true;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = true;
        jumpTimer = 0.7;
    }

    if(staminaBarDisplay >= 1) {
        staminaBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    if(staminaBarDisplay <= 0) {
        staminaBarDisplay = 0;
        canJump = false;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 6;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 6;
    }

    if(staminaBarDisplay < 0.2) {
        canJump = false;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
    }

    if(currentXP >= maxXP) {
        LevelUpSystem();
    }

    if(leveledUp) {
        if(Time.time > timeTillNotShowLevelUp) {
            leveledUp = false;
        }
    }
}

function Wait() {
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.1);
    canJump = false;
}

function LevelUpSystem() {
    currentXP = 0;
    maxXP = maxXP + 50;
    level++;

    leveledUp = true;
    timeTillNotShowLevelUp = Time.time + timeToShowLevelUp;

    healthBarDisplay += 1;

    hungerBarDisplay += 1;

    thirstBarDisplay += 1;

    staminaBarDisplay += 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you cut down the code and show only the relevant parts please

Comment: I get a similar error for the other ones as well but didn't want to post all 40 errors that look almost the same. Type '[Assembly-UnityScript]PlayerGUI' has an extra field 'hungerFallRate' of type 'System.Int32' in the player and thus can't be serialized (expected 'healthFallRate' of type 'System.Int32') UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Comment: In unityscript, do you not have to initialise your float vars as 1.0f? or 1f? I'm unfamiliar with anything other than C# in unity, and I know that always trips me up.

Comment: Something else was weird, don't know what. A program restart fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same problem.I think you build by command line options.And you not set Buildtarget before building, Solution is to set target.like:

/Applications/Unity5_2/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -batchmode -quit -executeMethod YOUR_BUILD_METHOD -projectPath YOUR_ROJECT_PATH **-buildTarget ios**

And than you fix this problem .